# Determine SQL Server Version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I determine the version of SQL 2005 Server on a machine.

**I need to know if it is a Server license or a Processor license.**

I've found

```
select serverproperty('LicenseType'), serverproperty('NumLicenses')
```

which returns:

DISABLED    NULL

Also found this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlblog/archive/2006/11/10/tracking-license-information-in-sql-2005.aspx

But is altering the registry the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you installed SQL Server via a Volume License Agreement it will show as DISABLED NULL when you run the query that you posted.

Our SQL Server (which is legit and installed via a volume license agreement) doesn't return license information as the volume license installer doesn't ask for license information.

Your most reliable way to check on licenses is to find the paperwork from when it was purchased.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server no longer tracks licensing - if you want to enable it you can modify the registry (unconfirmed)- see [this Microsoft Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlblog/archive/2006/11/10/tracking-license-information-in-sql-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that licensing is disabled on your server.  Perhaps it's SQL Express or SQL Developer edition, neither of which have licensing requirements in the sense of Per Seat / Per Processor licensing.

Here is the [**MSDN reference page for SERVERPROPERTY()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396(SQL.90).aspx) for SQL 2005 that lists all of the possibilities.

Comment: That documentation is incorrect, as the `LicenseType` and `NumLicenses` server properties are useless ever since SQL Server 2005: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/295301/serverproperty-licensetype-returns-disabled-on-any-sql-server-2005-install

Answer (score 0):

Check your edition as well.  For Developer edition, the LicenseType will return 'disabled'

```
select serverproperty('LicenseType'), 
       serverproperty('NumLicenses'), 
       serverproperty('Edition');
```